# AutoLayout not working in PrimeNG TurboTable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I can't get autoLayout to work in the new TurboTable for PrimeNG. All the columns have the same width, regardless of content and the browser width.

I've tried `[autoLayout]="true"` as well as `autoLayout="true"`. Neither works.

I'm using the latest PrimeNG version (5.2.4)

Here is my html :

```
<p-card>
    <p-header>
        <div style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px">
            <button pButton
                    type="button"
                    label="Add New"
                    class="ui-button-info"
                    icon="fa-plus"
                    [routerLink]="['/users/edit', 0]"></button>
        </div>
    </p-header>
    <p-table [columns]="cols"
             [value]="users"
             [autoLayout]="true"
             [(selection)]="selectedUser"
             selectionMode="single"
             [style]="{'height':'600px'}"
             [scrollable]="true"
             scrollHeight="580px"
             [rows]="20"
             (onRowSelect)="handleOnUsersRowSelect($event)">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                    {{col.header}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
                <td *ngFor="let col of columns" style="text-align: center">
                    {{col.field == 'isActive' ? (rowData[col.field] ? 'Yes' : 'No'): rowData[col.field] }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</p-card>
```

Comment: It looks like the problem occurs if the table is set to scrollable. If it is set to use pages, autolayout works

Comment: I have the same problem and for now I don't find solution. I can confirm the behavior from the first comment.

Comment: @makkasi I wound up going with pages instead of autoscroll as the autolayout works in that mode. I have not tried it again since the OP nor since upgrading to the latest version of primeng

Answer (score 5):

The `scrollable` and `resizable` properties are not compatible with the `autoLayout` property, for technical reason.

This is documented in PrimeNg site.