# primeng data table columns width autofit based on contents

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am using prime ng data table in my angular application, I want to adjust width based on the content without giving fixed width it should adjust automatically. Can anyone help me with this?
[image: in this image I want to reduce width of the mobile number column to fit the content without spaces]

```
<p-table #dataGrid [columns]="columns" [value]="data" [paginator]="columns.length > 0 ? paginator : false"
  [rowsPerPageOptions]="rowsPerPageOptions" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [first]="first"
  [reorderableColumns]="true" [resizableColumns]="true" [(rows)]="rows" [lazy]="lazy" [lazyLoadOnInit]="false"
  (onLazyLoad)="loadData($event)" [loading]="loading" selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="rowSelect($event)"
  (onColReorder)="saveStateToSession()" (onPage)="paginationEvent();" [sortOrder]="sortOrder" [ngClass]="{'disabledrow':disabledRow}"
  (onRowReorder)="updatePriority($event)">
<!---Some data---->
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 2):

in case anyone is still struggling with this:

do use:
`[autoLayout]="true"`

but remove:
`[resizeableColumns]="true"` and `[scrollable]="true"`

the scrollable and resizable properties are not compatible with the autoLayout property, for technical reasons. per: [AutoLayout not working in PrimeNG TurboTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779510/autolayout-not-working-in-primeng-turbotable)

this will get you columns that are as wide as the content determines them to be.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

`<p-table [resizableColumns]="true" [autoLayout]="true">`

Comment: If I use [resizableColumns]="true" then the columns are manually resizable means we can adjust that column width but I want it to adjust width based on the content in it.

Comment: If I use  [autoLayout]="true" it's not displaying full width.

Comment: can you update your question with the html snippet?

Comment: Can you check once now?

Answer (score 0):

The scrollable and resizable properties are not compatible with the autoLayout property, for technical reason.

```js
<p-table
    #dt
    [value]="records"
    [columns]="cols"
    responsiveLayout="scroll"
    dataKey="userid"
    styleClass="p-datatable-sm"
    [loading]="!loadingSpinner"
    [columns]="cols"
    [exportFilename]="exportName"
    [rows]="100"
    [(contextMenuSelection)]="selectedItem"
    scrollHeight="450px"
    [tableStyle]="{ width: 'max-content'}"
    [autoLayout]="true"
    columnResizeMode="expand"
    [contextMenu]="cm"
    (onEditComplete)="editGrid($event)"
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[100, 200, 500]"
  >
```